# Online Editor for Python

Tags: python

Can somebody explain me why I am getting an error from this online editor?
My code is here: http://codepad.org/Yx2VSml2

Comment: CodePad probably blocks that for security reasons.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the functionality of an external site.

Answer (score 7):

When you call `urllib.urlopen()` you're trying to open a network connection. For security reasons, any online editor should disallow such operations.

Answer (score 6):

From the stacktrace:

> IOError: [Errno socket error] (-2, 'Name or service not known')

This looks like a failed DNS resolution.

It is likely that networking is banned from Codepad: this would make sense, from a security point of view.

Answer (score 5):

Online code editors often block network access for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> If the connection cannot be made the IOError exception is raised

From the documentation for [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface)